# Will like to clarify what does row space mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Trying to clarify the following solution:

[image]

In the solution, $d$ is solvable when $d$ is in row space. The row space here is referring to $A$? i.e $row(A)$? My understanding is that for $d$ to be solvable it has to be in the column space of $A^{T}$. Since the column space of $A^{T}$ is the row space of $A$, I am inferring that the row space mentioned in the solution is $A$.

My next question is whether the left nullspace mentioned in the solution is referring to $N(A^{T})$?

Comment: The row space of $A$ is the same as the image/range of $A^T$. The left nullspace is indeed the nullspace of $A^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $A\in M_n,m$ a matrix, we call row space to the subspace of vectors:
$$\text{span}(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)$$
Being $v_i$ the "$i$-st" row of A.

In your particular case, it's asking for $A$'s row space, so it's $A^T$ column space (same as before but with the column vectors of $A^T$).

And yes, $N(A^T)$ is $A^T$'s null space. In addition, if $N(A^T)=(0,...,0)$, then any 2 different row vectors in $A$ are linearly independent.

Comment: hmm i think they are referring to A row space see my edited part again.

Comment: Yes, you're right, i'll edit it. Thanks for the aclaration.